# Invisible items becomes visible on scroll in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, visibility

I have two buttons to play and pause a track in a RecyclerView item. When play button tapped, I want to hide it and show pause button. I've done this and it's working but I have a problem. Once I scroll to (down or up), the play button appears again and pause button disappears. I also have a progress bar to show the time of the track. As the track play, the bar fills out and its progress is zero at the beginning. When I scroll the list, this progress bar also resets to zero and doesn't move but the track continues to play. I tried three ways to fix this:

1. Setting setIsRecyclable to false
2. Adding and else condition to views
3. Adding default visibility to the views in the XML file

Here's my complate code:

```
class BackstageProcessorAdapter(private val stickyHeaderChangedCallback: (ProcessorGroupId) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(),
        StickyHeaderItemDecoration.StickyHeaderInterface {

    private var callback: ProcessorViewHolderCallback? = null
    private var backStageProcessorItemList = emptyList<BackStageProcessorItem>()
    private var stickyHeaderPosition = 0
    private val processorGroupHeaderPositionMap = mutableMapOf<ProcessorGroupId, Int>()
    private var parentRecyclerViewHeight = 0
    private var lastItemPosition = 0
    private var currentPreviewSound: String = ""
    private var processorHeaderNameForEvent: String = ""
    private lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer
    var prevHolder: ProcessorViewHolder? = null
    var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    fun registerCallback(callback: ProcessorViewHolderCallback) {
        this.callback = callback
    }

    fun setItems(items: List<BackStageProcessorItem>) {
        if (backStageProcessorItemList.isNotEmpty()) return
        backStageProcessorItemList = items
        var headerPos = 0
        for ((index, item) in items.withIndex()) {
            if (item is BackStageProcessorItem.Header) {
                headerPos = index
                processorGroupHeaderPositionMap[item.processorGroupUiModel.processorGroupId] =
                        headerPos
            }
            item.headerPosition = headerPos
        }
        lastItemPosition = items.lastIndex
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            HEADER_ITEM -> HeaderViewHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_processor_header))
            else -> ProcessorViewHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_backstage_processor))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (val backStageProcessorItem = backStageProcessorItemList[position]) {
            is BackStageProcessorItem.Header -> {
                (holder as HeaderViewHolder).bindTo(backStageProcessorItem)
            }

            is BackStageProcessorItem.Content -> {
                (holder as ProcessorViewHolder).bindTo(backStageProcessorItem.processorUiModel)
                holder.setMargin(position)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (backStageProcessorItemList.get(position)) {
            is BackStageProcessorItem.Header -> HEADER_ITEM
            else -> PROCESSOR_ITEM
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = backStageProcessorItemList.size

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        recyclerView.post {
            parentRecyclerViewHeight = recyclerView.height
        }
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        callback = null
    }

    override fun getHeaderPositionForItem(itemPosition: Int) =
            backStageProcessorItemList[itemPosition].headerPosition

    override fun getHeaderLayout(headerPosition: Int) = R.layout.item_processor_header

    override fun bindHeaderData(header: View, headerPosition: Int) {
        val headerItem = backStageProcessorItemList[headerPosition] as BackStageProcessorItem.Header
        (header as TextView).setText(headerItem.processorGroupUiModel.nameResId)
        if (headerPosition != stickyHeaderPosition) {
            stickyHeaderPosition = headerPosition
            stickyHeaderChangedCallback(headerItem.processorGroupUiModel.processorGroupId)
        }
    }

    override fun isHeader(itemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        if (itemPosition == backStageProcessorItemList.size) return true
        return backStageProcessorItemList[itemPosition] is BackStageProcessorItem.Header
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
    }

    fun getHeaderPositionViewGroupId(processorGroupId: ProcessorGroupId): Int {
        return processorGroupHeaderPositionMap[processorGroupId]!!
    }

    inner class HeaderViewHolder(itemView: View) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindTo(header: BackStageProcessorItem.Header) {
            (itemView as TextView).setText(header.processorGroupUiModel.nameResId)
        }
    }

    inner class ProcessorViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val textViewProcessorName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewProcessorName)
        private val textViewProcessorDescription = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewProcessorDescription)
        private val imageViewProcessorImage = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewProcessorImage)
        private val buttonAddProcessor = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonAddProcessor)
        private val buttonUnlockEverything = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.buttonUnlockEverything)
        private val buttonPlayPreview = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonPlayPreview)
        private val buttonPausePreview = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonPausePreview)

        fun setMargin(position: Int) {
            val margin =
                    if (position != lastItemPosition) dpToPx(20)
                    else {
                        val contentHeight = getDimen(R.dimen.backstage_processor_item_height)
                        val headerHeight = getDimen(R.dimen.processor_header_height)
                        val topMargin = dpToPx(20)
                        parentRecyclerViewHeight - (contentHeight + headerHeight + topMargin)
                    }
            (itemView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).bottomMargin = margin
        }

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        fun bindTo(processor: ProcessorUiModel) {
            val processorId = processor.processorId
            val canProcessorBeEnabled = callback?.canProcessorBeEnabled(processorId) == true
            val isProcessorAdded = callback?.isProcessorAddedBefore(processorId) == true
            val processorName = itemView.context.resources.getText(processor.nameId).toString()
            val processorNameForEvent = processorName.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_")

            this.setIsRecyclable(false)
            if (prevHolder != null) prevHolder?.setIsRecyclable(false)
            imageViewProcessorImage.setImageResource(processor.storeIconResId)
            textViewProcessorName.setText(processor.nameId)
            textViewProcessorDescription.setText(processor.descriptionId)

            buttonUnlockEverything.isVisible = canProcessorBeEnabled.not()
            buttonAddProcessor.isGone = canProcessorBeEnabled.not()
            buttonAddProcessor.isEnabled = isProcessorAdded.not()
            this.setIsRecyclable(false)

            buttonAddProcessor.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                return@setOnTouchListener when (event.action) {
                    KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        v.alpha = 0.75f
                        true
                    }
                    KeyEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        v.alpha = 1f
                        callback?.addProcessor(processorId)
                        true
                    }

                    else -> v.onTouchEvent(event)
                }
            }

            buttonPlayPreview.setOnClickListener {
                if (currentPreviewSound.isNotEmpty()) {
                    pausePreviewSound()
                }

                if (currentPreviewSound.isNotEmpty() && prevHolder != this) {
                    currentPreviewSound = ""
                    prevHolder?.itemView?.buttonPausePreview?.isVisible = false
                    prevHolder?.itemView?.buttonPlayPreview?.isVisible = true
                } else {
                    prevHolder?.itemView?.buttonPausePreview?.isVisible = true
                    prevHolder?.itemView?.buttonPlayPreview?.isVisible = false
                }

                processorName.playPreviewSound(processorNameForEvent)

                prevHolder = this
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            buttonPausePreview.setOnClickListener() {
                pausePreviewSound()
            }

            buttonUnlockEverything.setOnClickListener {
                getHeaderNameClickProcessorForEvent()
                callback!!.sendEvent("goPremiumClicked", processorHeaderNameForEvent, processorName)
                callback?.openInAppBilling()
            }

        }

        private fun String.playPreviewSound(processorNameForEvent: String) {
            callback?.stopVG()
            currentPreviewSound = this
            buttonPlayPreview.isVisible = false
            buttonPausePreview.isVisible = true
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(itemView.context, AmpSoundType.getAmpType(this))
            mediaPlayer?.start()

            val maxTrackDuration = mediaPlayer?.duration!!
            itemView.progressBarPreview.max = maxTrackDuration
            itemView.progressBarPreview.progress = 0

            // The first arg of the CountDownTimer is the tick count. Which is (maxTrackDuration (lets say this is 18000) / 1000) = 18 ticks in total duration with 200ms interval
            timer = object : CountDownTimer(maxTrackDuration.toLong(), 200) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    updatePreviewSoundProgressBar()
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    setPlayButton()
                }
            }

            timer.start()

            callback!!.sendEvent("playClicked", processorHeaderNameForEvent, processorNameForEvent)
        }

        private fun pausePreviewSound() {
            setPlayButton()
            mediaPlayer?.stop()
            timer.cancel()
        }

        private fun setPlayButton() {
            buttonPlayPreview.isVisible = true
            buttonPausePreview.isVisible = false
        }

        private fun updatePreviewSoundProgressBar() {
            itemView.progressBarPreview.progress += 200
        }

        private fun getHeaderNameClickProcessorForEvent() {
            val processorHeaderPosition = backStageProcessorItemList[getHeaderPositionForItem(position)]
            val processorHeaderData = (processorHeaderPosition as BackStageProcessorItem.Header).processorGroupUiModel.nameResId
            val processorHeaderName = itemView.context.resources.getString(processorHeaderData)
            processorHeaderNameForEvent = processorHeaderName.toLowerCase().substring(0, 3)
        }

        private fun dpToPx(dp: Int) = (dp * itemView.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()

        private fun getDimen(dimenRes: Int) = itemView.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(dimenRes)

    }
}
```

And a part of my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutHearTone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.46"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPausePreview"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            tools:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_preset_view_pause" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlayPreview"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_preset_view_play" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarPreview"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:minWidth="140dp"
        android:progress="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You probably missing the else part in your code . You have to cover Both cases in bindViewHolder because of recyclable nature of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I wrote an else state in `playPreviewSound` function but it didn't work. Even if I add an else code for the button, what about the progress bar? It's also behaving strange

Comment: When you change the visibility of an item do you also change the state of the data item that's backing this adapter?

Comment: I"m sorry, what do you mean by `backing this adapter`?

Comment: @tpbafk I mean the individual `BackStageProcessorItem` that you are getting the data from in order to set visibility.

Comment: No. I even haven't add any data to `BackStageProcessorItem` about buttons. I guess that's the problem. I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView`s work by creating a pool of `ViewHolder` objects (got by calling `onCreateViewHolder`) which are used to display stuff. No matter how many items the view represents, there are only a handful of `ViewHolder`s being used, enough to fill the visible part of the `RecyclerView` and a few either side so you can peek to the next item.

So it works by shuffling those `ViewHolder`s around to put them ahead of the scrolling, and the stuff they're displaying gets updated to represent a particular item in the list. This is done in `onBindViewHolder`.

Basically, if you have items with *state*, i.e. whether the play button is visible, whether a seek bar is at a particular position, if it has some kind of controller attached that updates the seek bar - you need to restore all that in `onBindViewHolder` when that item comes into view and a `ViewHolder` is being told to display that item. That means you have to keep track of that state somewhere (usually in the *adapter*), so you can restore it when an item pops into view.

Answer (score 0):

recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0,0);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34887333)